# Which folders and files needed 777 mode in joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

After joomla upload to ftp . how many folder needed mode 777 need enable to working joomla without any error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the security configuration of your Web server the recommended default permissions of 755 for directories and 644 for files should be reasonably secure.

source: http://docs.joomla.org/What_are_the_recommended_file_and_directory_permissions%3F

Comment: Also, if you are still having problems with Joomla! when your folders are set to 755, you have a HOSTING issue and not a Joomla! issue.

Answer (score 2):

Only bad hosting providers will require you to set permissions to 777. If you have to do that, or are told to do that by your host, save yourself and get a better host. I don't deal with clients on hosts like that, because its the source of a LOT of security issues.

Answer (score 1):

never use 777 but use 755.

755 only for writeable folders like components, modules, templates, caches and images.

except for that .. set to 664

Answer (score 0):

None.

Joomla 1.5 contains an option that uses your FTP account and password to write to files it needs to write to. Enable that and none of them need to be world writeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which folders to chmod in system check of your joomla admin

Answer (score -1):

The only file that needs to be writable is configuration.php. It should be set to 666.

You can find the list of folders by going to the Joomla admin area (the 'administrator' folder in your Joomla installation). Go to **Help > System info** in the menu then click **Directory permissions**. This page tells you whether they are writable or not. Folders should be set to 777.

Answer (score -1):

To solve installation errors I have found setting the following directories to 777 to be very convenient BUT EXTREMELY UNSAFE.

/administrator/backups/

/administrator/components/

/administrator/language/

/administrator/language/en-GB/

/administrator/language/nl-NL/

/administrator/modules/

/administrator/templates/

/components/

/images/

/images/banners/

/images/stories/

/language/

/language/en-GB/

/language/nl-NL/ or other lang

/language/pdf_fonts/

/modules/

/plugins/

/plugins/content/

/plugins/editors/

/plugins/editors-xtd/

/plugins/search/

/plugins/system/

/plugins/user/

/plugins/xmlrpc/

/tmp/

/templates/

/cache/